How can I set the orders like this in Bootstrap 5?
Here is the code:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="example1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <img class="img-fluid me-5" src="example2" alt="">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark px-5 py-2 fw-semibold fs_14">TERVEZZ SAJÁT SZÍNEKKEL</button>
    </div>
    <h1 class="fw-light mt-5 mb-4">N2001<sup class="ms-1 fs-4">4.13</sup></h1>
    <div class="d-flex fs_20">
      <p class="me-3 mb-0">nettó</p>
      <p class="me-3 mb-0">25.500 Ft</p>
      <p class="me-3 mb-0">&frasl;</p>
      <p class="mb-0">m<sup class="">2</sup></p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex opacity_60 mb-4">
      <p class="me-3">bruttó</p>
      <p class="me-3">35.000 Ft</p>
      <p class="me-3">&frasl;</p>
      <p>m<sup class="">2</sup></p>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex">
      <p class="me-3">szükséges</p>
      <p class="me-3">100</p>
      <p class="me-3">&or;</p>
      <p>m<sup class="">2</sup></p>
    </div>
    <p class="opacity_80 mb-5 text-black">Javasoljuk, hogy számolj további 10-15%-kal, a vágási hulladék miatt.</p>

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark px-5 py-2 fw-semibold fs_14 me-5">AJÁNLATOT KÉREK</button>
      <input class="form-check-input fs-4 me-2 mt-0" type="checkbox" value="" aria-label="checkbox">
      <p class="fs_12 m-0 align-items-center d-flex text-black">SEGÉDANYAG HOZZÁADÁSA</p>
    </div>
    <p class="opacity_80">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>



I would like to put this div onto the first place on mobile (sm breakpoint):
<div class="d-flex">
  <img class="img-fluid me-5" src="example2" alt="">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark px-5 py-2 fw-semibold fs_14">TERVEZZ SAJÁT SZÍNEKKEL</button>
</div>


After that:
<img class="img-fluid" src="example1" alt="">
And then the rest.
My problem is that I need to highlight the image in the first col, and the remaining two parts are in the other two col. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance for any help!
I tried the 'order' element but i cannot figure it out.

order only works within a flex parent, but the element you want to move this after, isn't even a sibling. The easiest solution here would probably be, that you put the code into both locations to begin with (careful not to duplicate any IDs), and then use the display utility classes to get one of them shown and the other hidden, and vice versa. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/

slight correction: oder only works within either flexbox or css-grid. However, you should note, that it will have a negative impact on your accessibility rating.
